# How do I navigate to slightly above an anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, anchor

I know how to navigate to a given anchor tag on a page - what I'm trying to do is link to a part of the page that is 30-40 pixels above the target anchor. The reason for this is that I have a bootstrap navigation that ends up covering part of the relevant content if I like directly to the part of the page with the anchor.

Currently I have this for the link:

```
%a{:href => root_path + "#how_it_works"} How It Works
```

and on the page it links to:

```
.span12#how_it_works
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the link to navigate to a section of the page that is slightly above the .span12#how_it_works?

Comment: Are you using twitter bootstrap? If so, tag your question with it. Are you using [affix](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I got a nifty idea to trick your browser. No javascript needed.

Create a div tag, give it a name. Have the div be empty. Then in CSS use positioning to move it up how far you want.

```
position: relative;
top: -165px;
```

You could play around with relative or absolute position depending on where you want it.

Then simply make that div tag the anchor tag.

```
<div class="anchor_placement" id="anchor"></div>
```

When you go to the anchor, it will go to wherever the div tag is.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to hack around this by adding some extra padding in your css, but the surest way to do this is with javascript:

```
$('a[href="#how_it_works"]').on('click',function(e){
  // prevent normal scrolling action
  e.preventDefault();
  // grab the target url from the anchor's ``href``
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
     if (target.length) {
           window.scrollTo(0, target.offset().top - 50); // <-- our offset in px adjust as necessary
      return false;
  }
});
```

Here's [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iyzfD).

This uses a modified version of Chris Coyier's [smooth scroll script](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/). I've taken the "smoothness" out of the scrolling, but you could add it back in by animating the scrolltop like so:

```
   if (target.length) {
     $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top + 20
    }, 1000);
    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?
[live example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/d5L3g/show)
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/d5L3g/)

I've added a top padding to the anchors:
**CSS**

```
a.anchor{
background-color:pink;
padding-top:30px;
display:block;
margin-top:-30px; /* if you want to cancel out the padding-top */
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <a href="#section1">section1</a><br>
  <a href="#section2">section2</a><br>
  <a href="#section3">section3</a><br>
  <a href="#section4">section4</a><br>  
  ....  
  <a name="section1" class="anchor">section1</a>  
  etc
```

**EDIT**
Re-reading your question, if the problem is because you are using bootstrap with an affixed navbar and some of your page content is hidden beneath the navbar, an even easier solution is to add padding to the top of the page body to move the page content lower.

If you need to do this on every page of the site, use:
**CSS**

```
body {
padding-top:40px;
}
```

If you only need to clear the navbar on selected pages, add a class to the body tag on the offending pages and target just those specific pages, eg
**HTML**

```
<body class="welcome">  
....
```

**CSS**

```
 body.welcome {
padding-top:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery scrollTo plugin?  Seems like this has been used with some tweaking to do what you want. See the scenario/answer here [Jquery ScrollTo issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412259/jquery-scrollto-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Gu3miles - This worked perfectly for me - I am using the anchors with a persistent navigation bar.

```
.anchorplace{position: relative;
top: -74px; }

<div class="anchorplace" id="challenge"></div>
```